# Problema al instalar MySQL (5.7.15) en macOS Sierra (10.12)

Tags: mysql, macos

Acabo de actualizar mi MacBook-Air (2013) a macOS Sierra y cuando intento instalar MySQL (mysql-5.7.15-osx10.11-x86_64.dmg) se instala correctamente pero cuando intento hacer un :

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

o

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

me aparece:

**ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!**

Comment: Deberías aportar como haz instalado mysql en tu sistema... ya que puede cambiar las rutas según que software package usaste...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para solucionar el problema haremos lo siguiente:
1) Identificamos el archivo PID, en mi caso está en la ruta:

```
/usr/local/mysql/data/{nombreDeUsuario}.pid
```

NOTA1: Si no puden ingresar a data por problemas de permiso:

```
sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/mysql/data
```

NOTA2: Para saber cual es la ruta del PID pueden intentar hacer un "server start":

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

y ahí cuando les marque el ERROR, les va a aparecer. En mi caso es:

```
/usr/local/mysql/data/faca-air.local.pid
```

2) Identificamos el archivo de configuración, en mi caso está en la ruta:

```
/usr/local/data/mysql/auto.cnf
```

3) Le damos permisos con :

```
sudo chmod 775 auto.cnf
```

4) Lo abrimos con VIM:

```
vim auto.cnf
```

5) Agregamos la siguiente línea al final del archivo:

```
pid-file = /usr/local/var/mysql/{nombreDeUsuario}.pid
```

6) Reinicien su mac.

NOTA: Recuerden reemplazar los lugares donde dice {nombreDeUsuario}.pid por el nombre de usuario de su mac; en mi caso faca-air (faca-air.local.pid)

NOTA2: Si no les llega a funcionar, hagan el mismo procedimiento pero con la siguiente ruta del archivo PID:

```
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.15-osx10.11-x86_64/data/{nombreDeUsuario}.pid
```

Comment: Con permisos 775 no sería suficiente? Por no dejar tantos permisos a otros a usuarios. Un saludo.

Comment: Si, es correcto. Muchas gracias por tu aporte. Saludo

Answer (score 0):

No instale la 5.7 porque .... me fue imposible hacerla funcionar, lo intente con la 5.6 y mismo problema pero sigueindo esta explicacion y usando la ruta de la nota 2 funciono si bien no de primeras si a la segunda intentona. Recordar este orden:

1º Apagar el servidor en panel de preferencias del sistema.
2º Arrancarlo desde terminal con sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
3º Apagarlo con sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop

Por este orden si me funciono.

Un millo de gracias, continuo ..... con SQL a ver que me encuentro ahora. Ya le estoy "pillando" miedo ;)